# C# selenium find an element by text then click on checkbox

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to search for example (UK) then click on checkbox that is in the same row

**HTML** (but **tr** can increase or decrease)

```
<tr class="ng-scope table-row-style">
    <td class="ng-binding">US</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">United States</td>
    <td class="btn-td" style="padding: 0;">
        <input type="checkbox" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="ng-scope table-row-style">
    <td class="ng-binding">UK</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">United Kingdom</td>
    <td class="btn-td" style="padding: 0;">
        <input type="checkbox" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="ng-scope table-row-style">
    <td class="ng-binding">IN</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">India</td>
    <td class="btn-td" style="padding: 0;">
        <input type="checkbox" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by

```
IList<IWebElement> tableRow = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
IList<IWebElement> rowTD;
if (tableRow.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (IWebElement row in tableRow)
    {
        rowTD = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
        if (rowTD[0].Text.Equals("UK"))
            rowTD[2].Click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the parent `tr` element based on child `td` containing the desired text and then find the child `input` element as following:

```cs
//tr[.//td[contains(.,'UK')]]//input
```

The entire Selenium command finding and clicking this element could be

```cs
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[.//td[contains(.,'UK')]]//input")).Click();
```

Comment: dose not work cause input inside another td

Comment: My XPath expression is locating a **parent** **tr** based on the text and then I'm going from that parent **tr** to it's child **input**. The **input** here is not inside the **td** containing that text. So, if you presented correct XML and correctly copied my XPath it should work.